# Using value of members in a list as the key to another list in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm new to Tcl. I want to use element-value in a list as the key to another list. 
So if I have:

```
set  mainlist  { list1 list2 }  
set  list1 { val1 val2 }
set  list1 { val3 val4 }
```

I would like to iterate on mainlist members to get list1 and list2 members.

I tried following but it did't work:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $list1]} {incr i}  {

  set  mem  [lindex $list1 $i] 

  for {set j 0} {$j < [llength $mem]} {incr j} {

     puts [lindex $mem $j]

   }
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: That first part doesn't make sense. Do you mean you have a data structure like this: `set mainlist {{val1 val2} {val3 val4}}` ?

Comment: Yes but I need to have $list1 and $list2 strings as well. That's why I need indirect access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, indirect variable access. Use `set` for this.

your code could be:

```
set  mainlist  { list1 list2 }  
set  list1 { val1 val2 }
set  list2 { val3 val4 }

foreach mem $mainlist {
    foreach val [set $mem] {
        puts $val
    }
}
```

Why don't you use nested lists?

**Edit**:
You use `$mem`, which has the value `list1` or `list2` respective. But you try to access the content of the variable `list1`, so you have to use `set varname` or `set $variable_with__varname`.

`foreach` is not only quicker, it is also more clear what intention you have.
See the [tcl.tk wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1015#pagetoc170ee165) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, This seems to work. Could you elaborate a little, why is my code incorrect? The reason that I used `lindex` was to make sure that I iterate the members in specified order. Does yours also guarantee this?

Comment: Yes. And it is also quicker. If you need the index, I suggest using `incr`.

Comment: @Majid When you use `$mem`, you are referring to `list1` (string), not the variable `$list1`. What makes the code refer to the variable `$list1` is to call the variable using `set`; here Johannes used `[set $mem]` to return the variable `$list1` (and the other variables in `$mainlist`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure either about what you're asking, but from the loops you did, it seems like you want to do something like this:

```
set list1 {key1 value1}
set list2 {key2 value2}
set mainlist [list $list1 $list2]
```

Note that you need to have the variables set before you put them in a list.

Now, if you have the key `key2`, to get the value `value2`, you can use the loops you did, made a bit differently:

```
set key "key2"
foreach i $mainlist {
    if {[lindex $i 0] == $key} {
         puts [lindex $i 1]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need of using "for" command. 
You can use following,

```
 set  mainlist  { list1 list2 }  

 set list1_mem  [lindex $mainlist  0]
 foreach val1 $list1_mem {
  puts $val1
 }
 set list2_mem  [lindex $mainlist  1]
 foreach val2 $list2_mem {
   puts $val2
 }
```

I am using the TCL 8.4 there more optimised ways in after versions.